# How might I approach working this set of mathematical functions into a function in processing?

Tags: processing, collision-detection, physics-engine

I have some functions, which, set together, should allow me to perform continuous collision detection, but I really am not sure how to approach the problem as far as writing it in processing:

```
t is time.
A is the location vector for the first sphere, B the second.
A1 and A2 are the start and end point for A, the same goes for B1 and B2.
rA and rB are the radii of the respective circles.
Apart from t, all these variables are readily accessed from circle objects I have already written - I am expecting t to be a value between 0-1.

d(t)=||A(t) - B(t)|| - rA - rB
A'(t) = A1 + (A2-A1)t
B'(t) = B1 + (B2-B1)t
d'(t) = ||A'(t) - B'(t)|| - rA - rB
```

Finding the roots of this equation will give the beginning and the end of the spheres' period of overlapping - this is achieved by setting d't = 0 in the final equation, then solving for t.

Here is a link to the tutorial I am attempting to follow:

https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-ii-collision-detection-for-solid-objects

Comment: Are you looking for algorithm or math?

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear - I want to write an algorithm in Processing - to find the roots of the last equation - i.e. when d'(t) = 0.

Comment: You reference some code you have already written, can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have solved the problem for myself, I will post my solution I came up with when I have the time to do so.

Comment: @JoeLambert Please do, somebody might be looking for the same answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to solve the problem. The physicsBall object has variables that store the location of the ball at the start and at the end of the frame "locationA" and "locationB" respectively - these are vectors.

As stated in my question, my objective was basically to solve the equations:

```
d(t)=||A(t) - B(t)|| - rA - rB
A'(t) = A1 + (A2-A1)t
B'(t) = B1 + (B2-B1)t
d'(t) = ||A'(t) - B'(t)|| - rA - rB
```

for t, as this would give me a time of impact for circles A and B: the code below takes a pair of balls, finds the time of impact between those balls so long as they collide within the time elapsed during the frame, and writes that time into the z slot of a vector that contains the index of the two balls (in an array of all the balls in the program) in the x and y slots. This pair of balls has been found because it passed both sweep and prune and axis aligned bounding box collision tests first, and if a value of t is found between 0 and 1, the collision will be resolved immediately after this step.

```
boolean detailedDynamicCollisionDetection(physicsBall ball1, physicsBall ball2, PVector pair) {

PVector A1 = ball1.locationA;
PVector A2 = ball1.locationB;
PVector B1 = ball2.locationA;
PVector B2 = ball2.locationB;

float M = B1.x - A1.x;
float N = B2.x - B1.x - A2.x + A1.x;
float O = B1.y - A1.y;
float P = B2.y - B1.y - A2.y + A1.y; 
float Q = pow(ball1.radius+ball2.radius, 2);

float quadA = pow(N, 2) + pow(P, 2);
float quadB = 2*(N*M + O*P);
float quadC = pow(M, 2) + pow(O, 2) - Q;

float t1, t2;

if (pow(quadB, 2) - 4*quadA*quadC < 0) {
  return false;
} else if (pow(quadB, 2) - 4*quadA*quadC == 0) {
  t1 = (-quadB)/(2*quadA);
} else {
  t1 = (-quadB+sqrt(pow(quadB, 2) - 4*quadA*quadC))/(2*quadA);
  t2 = (-quadB-sqrt(pow(quadB, 2) - 4*quadA*quadC))/(2*quadA);
  if (t1 < t2 && (t1 < 0 || t1 >1)) {
    return false;
  } else if (t2 < t1 && (t2 < 0 || t2 >1)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (t1 > t2) {
    t1 = t2;
  }
  ball1.colliding = true;
  ball2.colliding = true;
  pair.z = t1;
}

return true;


}
```